# Issue in Olympus App while Dialing

Tags: mobicents, restcomm, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am using Olympus as a prototype to create a call application. But when I dial a I get this message "Error Parsing SIP URI"... 
Can you please answer a few of my questions?

Question1: I am writing :22.23.228.238: in Domain. It is the default IP provided by RESTCOMM.
Is it right? Or I have to write any other IP Address.

Question2: While adding a new contact by clicking on Plus button, what should be entered in name and sip field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm assuming you are talking about the Android Olympus application, right? (Cause there are similar applications for iOS and Web)

On (1):

May I ask where you got the ip 22.23.228.238? Our old demo instance used to be at 23.23.228.238 (not 22.23.228.238), but it's no longer used.

Also, the Olympus Android application should work out of the box, that is without setting a Domain at all (it would be working on registrar-less mode) but still be able to make calls our Restcomm Cloud instance (cloud.restcomm.com)

If you definitely need to register then I'd suggest that you setup your own Restcomm instance using docker, which should be a snap to get you started. Here's a guide for this:

http://www.telestax.com/rapid-webrtc-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker/

On (2):

I think there's hint showing up there when the fields are empty to guide you. In any case for 'Name' you can use any type of identifier string, like 'Conference Restcomm App' and in the 'SIP' field you add a SIP URI, like: 'sip:+1235@cloud.restcomm.com'

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Antonis

Comment: As you said that, Olympus Android application should work out of the box, that is without setting a Domain at all (it would be working on registrar-less mode) but still be able to make calls our Restcomm Cloud instance (cloud.restcomm.com)... Do you mean the built-in app which I have downloaded from restcomm. Or I have to make any changes to make any calls?

Comment: You have 2 ways to install Olympus App for Android: 1. The fast one which is downloading the prebuilt .apk from https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk#latest-olympus-apk, and 2. Build the restcomm-olympus sample application from the github repo: https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/restcomm-olympus. Both should work out of the box with cloud.restcomm.com in registrar-less fashion (no need to add Domain that is)

Comment: Dear @atsakiridis Sir, I am still confused. I am not getting your point. As you commented above, I downloaded the apk file from github.. But it is still not dialing any number.Whenever I make a call, it randomly generates an IP address and at the end, it shows the dialog with following error.

RCConnect Error

Could not connect to cloud.restcomm.com/107.21.247.251:5060

Comment: Hi Alex, we'll need some more data to troubleshoot your issue: a. If you are building the Olympus App from Android Studio I will need the logcat to see what is going on b. If you are using the .apk I need you to first kill the App and redo the scenario and then tell me what was the exact time you tested and what timezone you are in so that I can go to TestFairy and find your session. You can also find us at IRC #restcomm channel in chat.freenode.net if you want to further discuss

Comment: On you other question about how to integrate the SDK in your own Android App. I would suggest to have a look at the quick start guide at http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start/, which explains how to start from scratch using the SDK. Moreover there's a reference doc for more details on the APIs: http://restcomm.github.io/restcomm-android-sdk/doc/http://restcomm.github.io/restcomm-android-sdk/doc/. And finally you can also chek 2 sample applications to see it in action at: https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples